# URL Directory as parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, directory, param

I would like to turn a URL directory into a parameter. How can this be done?

For Example

```
myurl.com/directory1/?param2=test1
myurl.com/directory2/?param2=test2
myurl.com/directory3/?param2=test3
```

to reflect this

```
myurl.com/index.php?param1=directory1&param2=test1
myurl.com/index.php?param1=directory2&param2=test2
myurl.com/index.php?param1=directory3&param2=test3
```

htaccess solution would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here was my solution to this in the end.

Inside my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.)?$ index.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I had to go through all my image sources and stylesheet sources and make sure I had a slash at the start of each source in order for the image to grab from the root directory and I also had to setup virtual hosts in WAMP for proper testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information, do you have code to pull the directories? is it coming from a database etc.

provide your current code block for this and we can help you to modify it.

Comment: I don't have a code block. I wanna do some URL rewriting so that when a user enters my site with this url myurl.com/directory1/?param2=test1 anything inbetween the two slashes isn't read as a directory but as a parameter for my to use in my index.php page. Does that make sense? This should just be a .htaccess edit

Comment: yes, its actually done in apache itself, more specifically in .htaccess files.

You will need to know id you have mod_rewrite operational on the server, if it is you need to turn it on in the htaccess file, This page can help you too.

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php this will generate your rules for the file.

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ this might be more help to you.